# How to solve the Maven Configuration Problem

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

So i try to configure Maven in pom.xml [add dependencies and properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jX7Mi.png)
But an error occured :[Problems:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Y0Tz.png) . I don't know how to fix this problem when i try mvn clean install, it didn't succeed
[mvn clean install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8gsk.png)[I try again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eRcW.png)

Can anyone know how to fix this problem ? I thought it will build Success and i can run Maven Project

Comment: have you tried removing first line from your pom.xml that starts with `http://maven.apache.org...`?

Comment: Does your build run on plain command line? Furthermore you are using version which long end of life version of spring boot (https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support)

Answer (score 0):

Remove that `http`line from top.

Try adding this line `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` on top of your `POM.xml`